# ApachePOI getText displays only part of text in docx

Tags: java, apache-poi

Please help me with getText in ApachePOI. Debugger reveled that getText shows only smart part of the text in docx. How can I solve it?

`

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open("Шаблон.docx"));
for (XWPFTable tbl : doc.getTables()) {
for (XWPFTableRow row : tbl.getRows()) {
for (XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {
for (XWPFParagraph p : cell.getParagraphs()) {
for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
String text = r.getText(0);`
```

Comment: `XWPFRun.getText` gets the text of one single text run of possibly multiple text runs within one single paragraph of possibly multiple paragraphs within one single table cell within one of the tables of all tables within the document. The concatenation of all the text run texts within the document results in all the plain text within the document. But of course it looses all formatting which are the text runs were made for.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make re-importing the XWPFDocument library again. It will solve your problem if I am not wrong.

Comment: are you sure you are using latest library?

Comment: Yep I downloaded it yesterday